# How to break in a pitchers glove?

Tags: baseball, mlb, maintenance, pitching

When I look at mlb pitchers their gloves seem to have a specific breakpoint compared to infielders/outfielders.

Any ideas on their breakpoints?

Comment: Where is the evidence that pitcher's gloves are broken in differently?

Answer (score 4):

I have played Division 1 baseball, and I was recruited to play both infield (SS) and pitch, so I have a little experience for this question.

Frankly speaking, the glove is all about preference by the player.  Personally, I hated breaking a glove in.  I felt as though breaking it in (even though it makes catching a lot easier) really broke down the fabric that makes the glove as special as it is.  I loved having a stiff glove because it didn't make the glove feel flimsy, but again that's personal preference.

Another thing to think about is the size of the player's glove.  As I am sure you know. Outfielder's gloves are supposed to be bigger than infielder's and pitchers due to them wanting to increase their range.  Same with infielder's and pitchers.  When I played infield I used 11 3/4 size glove but when I pitched I used a 11.5 and even 11.25 glove.  So in reference to your question, their breakpoint could be different due to the actual size of the glove, or the make of the glove, or the way they break it in (heat and oil, a lot of catch, etc).

So really to answer your question, the way a glove is broke in is totally dependent on user preference.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many different methods that can be used to "break-in" a baseball glove. I came an [ESPN article](http://espn.go.com/mlb/columns/story?columnist=caple_jim&id=5173365) that asked then current MLB players how they "break-in" their new glove. The responses range from using the microwave/oven to bake the gloves, others hit and pound on the gloves by various means and objects, with some just use it during practice and workouts or have others use it to get some wear on it.

Comment: I found that their are probably many different way that professionals and alike have found to "break in" their gloves

Answer (score 0):

Heat and oil and then lots of practice!